# Detect multiple objects with one statement

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am making a little game in winforms. I am aware of that winforms isn't really for making games. However it is just a small project to learn myself OOP in a way that I enjoy doing.

So the problem is. I want to detect collision on the grid map. So my plan was to tag them with Collision however then i would have to write a million statements since you need to reference the control before you can access the tag. And because it is build up in tiles they all have different names.

So is there a way to detect multiple objects with diffrent names by some sort of tag or whatever.

Small drawing to (try) simplify my question.

[image: Example]

So bassicly I want p the player to be able to collide with all the c's without having to write multiple if statements.

So if all the c's had one way of identifying them. It would be a really simple if statement.

Comment: Place all you `c`s in an array.  Iterate over the array.

Comment: @Dan-o That stille requires alot of work is there not a better way?

Answer (score 2):

If the Cs are UserControls, you can add them to a list programmically in Form's Load-event.

Make a list for all cUserControls:

```
List<cUserControl> cElements = new List<cUserControl> cElements = this.Controls.OfType<cUserControlItem>().ToList()
```

Then run this in the Form's **"Shown"** event:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is cUserControl) { cElements.Add(c); }
}
```

After this you can iterate over this filled list. It's always up to date, after you edit or add more C's to your form. Each time the player moves, check if is has collided with any of the C's in the created list. You can do this with foreach-loop too. You just have to find out a way to detect if they collide.

```
foreach (cUserControl c in cElements)
{
            int[][] pointData = new int[][] 
            { 
                new int[] { _control.Location.Y, _control.Location.Y + _control.Size.Height }, 
                new int[] { _control.Location.X, _control.Location.X + _control.Size.Width } 
            };

            foreach (Control sControl in cElements)
            {
                if (sControl == _control) continue;

                if (sControl.Location.Y >= pointData[0][0] && sControl.Location.Y <= pointData[0][1])
                {
                    if (sControl.Location.X >= pointData[1][0] && sControl.Location.X <= pointData[1][1])
                    {
                        // Match
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Be careful: `foreach (T t in someCollection)` does *not* filter `someCollection` to items of type `T`. On the contrary: Your code will fail if there is any control on the form which is *not* a `cUserControlItem`. What you probably wanted to write was: `List<cUserControl> cElements = this.Controls.OfType<cUserControlItem>().ToList()`.

Comment: Updated this code with @Heinzi 's example and also added collision code.